# Appending multiple lists , after printing them

Tags: python, list, append

I have a folder with hundreds of files: '1.csv', '2a.csv' and etc. All of them contains 2 columns: 1. Name 2. Value.
Problems: the following code is printing the name and values in a loop, considering each of the files separately. I have already tried appending them but without success. Moreover, there are several dulpicates which I tried to delete with "np.unique" but it gone wrong, and printed the same thing.
*New_array printing all lists but also the header of the columns (separated)

```
for file_name in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.csv*')): # reading the files
    data = np.genfromtxt(file_name, delimiter=',',dtype=None,encoding="utf8") # generating them to nd.array
    new_array = [tuple(row) for row in data]
    for i in new_array:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do this with pandas pretty easily:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
for file_name in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.csv*')):
    tmp = pd.read_csv(file_name, header=None).drop_duplicates()
    df = df.append(tmp)

# if you want to drop duplicates that may occur between files:
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
mylist = df.values.tolist()
for x in mylist:
    print(x)
```

prints from my dummy data:

```
[1, 2]
[8, 9]
[10, 11]
[3, 4]
[5, 6]
```

`mylist` will be a list of lists containing each pair of values from each row in each csv.

Comment: Note: if you aren't using pandas elsewhere this adds an unnecessary import/dependency

Comment: @PranavHosangadi everything is an unnecessary dependency. We could do this using Collections in a few more lines.

Comment: True, but I assumed OP uses numpy elsewhere in their program too. If they'd been using pandas, I doubt they'd try to read csv files using `np.genfromtxt` instead of `pd.read_csv`.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi True for sure. This is just a fairly simple question so I assume that OP is fairly new to python. Data manipulation on a csv file is pretty awesome in pandas so I figured I'd introduce them to the library.

Comment: Possible add here is "header = 0" , index_col = 'Something", than it will be possible to print the dataframe as is.

Comment: @TheUndecided yeah at this point OP could just print the df, I just wanted to address the point of printing a list of lists. Probably didn't need that and could've printed the df instead, but just incase OP needed the data structure of a lists of lists for something further in the code I thought I'd finish that way.

Answer (score 2):

`new_array = [tuple(row) for row in data]` creates a list of rows. Then you discard that list in the next iteration. Instead, I suggest the following:

```
# Make an empty list for all arrays we read from the files
all_data = []
for file_name in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.csv*')): 
    data = np.genfromtxt(file_name, delimiter=',',dtype=None,encoding="utf8") 

    # append the new array to our list of all data
    all_data.append(data)

# Now, once we read everything, use vstack to stack all arrays on top of each other
all_data_array = np.vstack(all_data)

# Now that everything is in one array, use unique
unique_data = np.unique(all_data_array, axis=0)
```

You can replace the loop with a list comprehension for a more pythonic way of doing things:

```
all_data = [np.genfromtxt(file_name, delimiter=",". dtype=None, encoding="utf8") for file_name in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.csv*'))]
```

[More info on `np.vstack` from the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html)